# How do I convert an Open3D voxel grid into a byte array that could be saved as a PNG?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, open3d

I'm using Open3D to convert a point cloud into a voxel grid. I want to make a PNG from a specific angle of the voxel grid. However, I don't need the PNG yet since I plan on converting the byte array to a PNG later on in my workflow. Is it possible to create a byte array for a 2D image from a 3D voxel grid? What libraries should I use? Does the Open3D voxel grid need to be formatted differently to work with these libraries?

This is the code I'm using to make the voxel grid:

```
pc = sampler.output_to_point_clouds(samples)[0]
#pc is the pointcloud

ndarrayColors = np.array([pc.channels.get("R"), pc.channels.get("G"), pc.channels.get("B")])
ndarrayColors = np.transpose(ndarrayColors)

pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(pc.coords)

pcd.scale(1 / np.max(pcd.get_max_bound() - pcd.get_min_bound()), center=pcd.get_center())
pcd.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(ndarrayColors)

voxel_grid = o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid.create_from_point_cloud(pcd, voxel_size=0.035)

voxels = voxel_grid.get_voxels()
```